# Why can't I buy this skill? (Mistfire Wolf)

Tags: guild-wars-2

I just reached level 30 and unlocked the ability to buy elite skills. There appear to be 5 choices, but only 4 of them are able to be purchased. The last one, Mistfire Wolf, gives no explanation as to why I can't buy it.

[image]

How can I buy this skill?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Summon Mistfire Wolf](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Summon_Mistfire_Wolf) skill is only available if you've purchased the Digital Deluxe upgrade or the Collector's Edition. As you apparently do not have either of these, then you cannot use it. Purchasing the [Digital Deluxe Upgrade](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Digital_Deluxe_Upgrade) (2,000 gems) in the Black Lion Trading Post will give you access to it. Getting your hands on a CE would as well, but they were released in very limited physical editions only, so you'd have a tough time finding one post-release.

Comment: That seems silly that there is no explanation saying why you can't buy it then. If they want to make money by people wanting the unlockable abilities they should let you know how to do it.